# How to configure Remmina to trigger the super key in the remote client and not in the host?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-management, remote-control, remmina

I use `Remmina` to do an interaction from the Host to the Remote Client, therefore

```
Host (Remmina running) ---> Remote Client
```

The Hosts can be either as Ubuntu, Peppermint or Fedora and the Remote Clients are Ubuntu. All the machines are within the same LAN.

Remmina works as expected, but exists a situation. When in the Host is pressed any of the following shortcuts:

- <kbd>super</kbd>
- <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>

They are always triggered in the Host and not in the Remote Client.

**Question**

- How to configure Remmina to trigger the super key in the remote client and not in the host?